# more Abbreviated XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, app.xaml

Can you more abbretviate following code...

```
<Button.Tag>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/ButtonIcons/ButtonIcon_Sound.png"/>
</Button.Tag>
```

in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define

```
"/WpfApplication1;component/Images/ButtonIcons/ButtonIcon_Sound.png"
```

as a StaticResource, then you would have something like,

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="{StaticResource SoundIcon}"/>
```

Also put this resource in a shared ResourceDictionary then you don't need to define it twice.